# Why activeadmin sometimes logout autometic?

Tags: heroku, activeadmin

[ActiveAdmin](http://activeadmin.info) is a good gem that can help us manage data so easy.

But one question is I use [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com) to run my project.After I login the admin page,do something and refresh the admin page,it logout autometic!

What is the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the controller's **session** has affect your project.

You can see this issue:

https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/pull/1173

---

[RailsAdmin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) is better than it.

But I suggest that you write all the source yourself.**Customize** is great.